# Router with good Firewall for office - total of 50 computers/devices including wifi devices

Tags: wireless-networking, router, connection

I am looking for a good Office Router that can handle good firewall rules, have logs, and ca support about 50 computers/devices connected with wire and wireless.

We had different models before, and even installed dd-wrt, but sometimes when there is some restriction rules, the router just hangs or starts acting weird on some connections.

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you call good firewall rules, you can just use a refurbished computer, install Linux or BSD and voilà. This will allow you to have a very good firewall, with contrack and so on. You can also use helper software to write your rules.
Remember to automaticaly backup the firewall rules each night and/or use a CVS.

You don't absolutly need two network cards, but this is safer and simplier to have two.